# Adding two IEEE754 floating-point representations and interpreting the result.

Tags: binary, floating-point

This isn't for any class or homework. As part of my personal study, I'm trying to better understand the IEEE754 representation of decimal floating-point numbers in binary. I'd like to add two numbers: $1.111$ and $2.222$, then compare the result by converting the IEEE754 representation of the sum back to decimal.

Per [this online tool](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html):

- $1.111 = 00111111100011100011010100111111$
- $2.222 = 01000000000011100011010100111111$

Summing these two together using signed binary addition, I get:

$0111 1111 1001 1100 0110 1010 0111 1110$

In hexadecimal, this is:

$7F9C6A7E$

And according to [this other version of the tool](https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/32bit.html), that corresponds to $NaN$.

What's going on here?

Comment: You can't expect doing _integer_ addition on _floating-point_ representations to give meaningful results.

Comment: How would I go about trying to do what I want to do here?

Comment: I have no idea what it is you want to do. Use floating-point addition rather than integer?

Comment: Yes, I was under the impression that once I have the two floating-point numbers represented as binary strings, I could simply add them together bit by bit and then translate the resulting 32-bit string to decimal floating point. The IEEE754 standard defines conversions in both directions (binary to decimal and decimal to binary).

Comment: You have to adjust them so they have the same mantissa before you add them.  You ought to read about what the IEEE754 representation is actually constructed.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah, derp. I completely overlooked that. Should I delete/close my question?

Comment: @AleksandrH I meant exponent, not mantissa, didn't I?

Comment: @saulspatz Yeah, np, I got what you meant.

Comment: That hex number looks really ugly. Might be better to format it as `\mathrm{}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot expect to use *integer* binary addition on two floating-point *representations* and get a meaningful result.

First, $1.111$ cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point. Your `00111111100011100011010100111111` is actually the IEEE-754 single precision representation of the number
$$ 1.11099994182586669921875 $$
which is the closest representable number to $1.111$. This breaks up as

```
  0      01111111        00011100011010100111111
sign  biased exponent  fractional part of mantissa
```

and stands for the number
$$ 1.00011100011010100111111_2 \times 2^{127-127} $$

The representation of $2.222$ is twice that, with the same mantissa but the exponent one higher. When we add them we must position the mantissas correctly with respect to each other:

```
   1.00011100011010100111111
+ 10.0011100011010100111111
----------------------------
= 11.01010101001111110111101
  11.0101010100111111011110   <-- rounded to 1+23 bits mantissa using round-to-even

 0    10000000   10101010100111111011110
sign biased exp    fractional mantissa
```

And the representation `01000000010101010100111111011110` corresponds to the number 
$$ 3.332999706268310546875 $$
Note that this is *not* the closest representable number to $3.333$, which would be the next one,
$$ 3.33329999446868896484375 $$
but the round-to-even rule led to rounding *down* the full result of the addition, which compounded the error inherent in the two inputs each being slightly smaller than $1.111$ and $2.222$.

Comment: I followed this well until we got to the $10.00...$ part. Why did the decimal point move one place to the right?

Comment: @AleksandrH: Because the second addend has a biased exponent of `10000000`, so it represents the number $1.\langle\mathit{mantissa}\rangle_2 \times 2^{128-127}$ -- in other words the binary points is shifted one position to the right.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @AleksandrH: The job of the exponent is to encode where the binary point is. That's what makes the representation "_floating_ point" -- you can move the point! In the $2.22$ representation the exponent is $1$ (after we subtract the fixed bias), meaning that the point is after **one** of the explicitly represented mantissa bits.